# Is there a R function that allows you to insert a variable inside a command?

Tags: r, string, object, eval

For example:
Imagine I have an object named "cors" which contains a string only ("Spain" for example). I would like then for "cors" to be replaced in the expression (1) below by "Spain", resulting in the expression (2):

```
#(1)
DF <- DF %>% filter(str_detect(Country, "Germany|cors", negate = TRUE))
```

```
#(2)
DF <- DF %>% filter(str_detect(Country, "Germany|Spain", negate = TRUE))
```

P.S: I know that in MATLAB this could be handled with the "eval()" command, though in R it apparently has a completely different applicability.

Comment: Can you please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example alpng with how your expected output should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have an object, then place it outside the `quotes` and use `paste/str_c` to create the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
cors <- "Spain"
pat <- str_c(c("Germany", cors),  collapse = "|")
DF %>%
    filter(str_detect(Country, pat, negate = TRUE))
```

---

Or another option is to string interpolate with `glue` (assuming `cors` object have only a single string element)

```
DF %>%
    filter(str_detect(Country, glue::glue("Germany|{cors}"), negate = TRUE))
```

---

Or this can be done in `base R` with `grepl`

```
pat <- paste(c("Germany", cors), collapse = "|")
subset(DF, !grepl(pat, Country))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want `eval`, you could do:

```
cors <- 'Spain'

DF <- DF %>% filter(
  eval(
    parse(text=paste0('str_detect(Country, "Germany|', cors, '", negate=TRUE)'))
  ))
```